# Did Hugh's individuality virus cause all the subsequent changes in Borg behavior?

Tags: star-trek, borg, retcon

The behavior of the Borg changed dramatically in First Contact and Voyager. Critics have called this "[ruined](http://www.megabearsfan.net/post/2011/05/02/How-Star-Trek-First-Contact-and-Voyager-ruined-the-Borg.aspx)" and a "[brain bug](http://www.stardestroyer.net/Empire/Essays/BrainBugs.html)".

Could the change in behavior be explained by Hugh's individuality virus affecting the Collective and fragmenting it into more and less competent factions?

Comment: Both answers to the dupe make it abundantly clear that Hugh's "*infection*" only spread to his home cube, not beyond.

Comment: Out-of-universe the change in Borg behaviour was largely driven by the fact that the crew of Voyager faced an enemy that had vastly more exciting technology that the Paramount props department had cannibalised from the First Contact film, allowing lots more interior shots and close-up shots of Borg. The plots were driven by the available kit.